# Android intercept the response body and headers from a WebView?

Tags: android, webview, kotlin

I need to intercept the responses coming back from the response and redirects of a webview as it's loading?

I need to read the headers during the redirect, and I need to read cookies coming back.

Is this possible? Looking at some samples on stackoverflow, most solutions use `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` but that only gives you access to the url, and not the full response

Comment: Explore `WebChromeClient` and `WebViewClient`Classes . AFAIK those are the only way to intercept the `WebView`.

Comment: I have already those don't do the job :(

Comment: @aryaxt Hi, did you find a way to do that? I have the exact same case now ;-)